# Ensuring HTML files open with FireFox

Tags: html, windows, firefox

Just like how Linux files can contain a top `#!open/with/this/program` line at the top, is there an equivalent line to add to HTML files to ensure it tries to open with Firefox first (assuming Firefox is located in its standard path).

I am referring to windows here.

Answer (score 0):

No. HTML is a markup language, and knows nothing about what's being used to look at it.

You can, though, have a shortcut that opens a specified HTML file in Firefox.